# How to extend css class with another style?

Tags: css

I have nearly 30 classes and I want to apply this classes to my button element. I don't want to add class attribute for every button element. Is there any way to create a new button class like;

```
.button{
        .rounded-corner
        .corner
        .button-effective
        //another 20 classes
}
```

Comment: Not with plain CSS.. you can use processors like SASS or Less.

Comment: @putvande Is there any other workaround except adding all css classes to all buttons one by one?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You will have to use a CSS preprocessor to do this.

#### SASS

**[placeholder](http://www.sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/placeholder-selectors)**

```css
%rounded-corner {}
%corner {}
%button-effective {}

.button {
  @extend %rounded-corner;
  @extend %corner;
  @extend %button-effective;

  /* Some other styles. */
}

.box {
  @extend %rounded-corner;
}
```

Compiles to:

```css
.button, .box {
  /* rounded-corner styles */
}

.button {
  /* corner styles here */
}

.button {
  /* button-effective styles here */
}

.button {
  /* Some other styles. */
}

/*
`.box` is NOT defined here because it only uses placeholders. So it
is placed where the placeholder is defined.
*/
```

**Note:** with placeholders, the CSS selector is added to wherever the placeholder is defined. Not where the selector is defined.

**[extend](http://www.sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend)**

```css
.rounded-corner {}
.corner {}
.button-effective {}

.button {
  @extend .rounded-corner;
  @extend .corner;
  @extend .button-effective
  // Continue with other classes.
}
```

Compiles to:

```css
.rounded-corner, .button {}
.corner, .button {}
.button-effective, .button {}
```

**[mixin](http://www.sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixins)**

```css
@mixin rounded-corner {}
@mixin corner {}
@mixin button-effective {}

.button {
  @include .rounded-corner;
  @include .corner;
  @include .button-effective
  // Continue with other classes.
}
```

Compiles to:

```css
.button {
  /* rounded-corner styles here */
  /* corner styles here */
  /* button-effective styles here */
}
```

#### LESS

LESS has a similar sytanx to SASS and also has *extend* and *mixin*, though LESS is a little more forgiving if you want to add one class' style to another. While I believe still considered a mixin in LESS, you can add one class style to another like the following without having to use a keyword.

```css
.rounded-corner {}
.corner {}
.button-effective {}

.button {
  .rounded-corner;
  .corner;
  .button-effective;
  // Continue with other classes.
}
```

Compiles to:

```css
.button {
  /* rounded-corner styles here */
  /* corner styles here */
  /* button-effective styles here */
}
```

Answer (score 11):

It will be possible in CSS4:

```
 :root {
  --toolbar-theme: {
    border-radius: 4px;
  };
  --toolbar-title-theme: {
    color: green;
  };
}

.toolbar {
  @apply --toolbar-theme;
  @apply --toolbar-title-theme;
}
```

For now, you need to use Sass/Less preprocessors.

Comment: Here it says `@apply` has been abandoned :/ https://tabatkins.github.io/specs/css-apply-rule/ https://www.xanthir.com/b4o00

Comment: [There is no such thing as CSS4. There will never be a CSS4](https://css-tricks.com/css4/).

Comment: "Deprecated in favor of ::part()" https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_part

Answer (score 10):

You could use the attribute selector and concatenate your classes; it would still involve adding a long class to your button element:

```
<button class="button-rounded-corner-effective">Your button</button>
```

OR

```
<button class="button rounded corner effective">Your button</button>
/* Which is exactly what you did not want to do,
   but the CSS below will apply all the same.
   This example to clarify, then. */
```

... and then your CSS will be:

```
[class*="button"]{/*Generic button styles*/}
[class*="rounded"]{/*Rounded styles*/}
[class*="corner"]{/*Corner styles*/}
[class*="effective"]{/*Effective styles*/}
```

You will need to be careful about the namespacing though - the wild card selector will match any class that has that matches the string.

For example:

```
[class*="round"]{/*Will match rounded*/}
```

Answer (score 7):

With [CSS modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules), you can use `composes`:

```
.className {
  color: green;
  background: red;
}

.otherClassName {
  composes: className;
  color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use Less or Sass. For me, Less is "easier" to integrate to your project and you will have this code :

```
.button{
    .rounded-corner
    .corner
    .button-effective
}
.secondClass{
    .button;
    // your style code
}
.thirdClass{
    .button;
    // your style code
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are describing a `mixin` or an `extends`, which is possible currently if you use a CSS Preprocessor like LESS or SASS. CSS Preprocessors allow you to write non-CSS with extra features, and then run it through the preprocessor to convert it into regular CSS which is given to the browser.

It's not possible in regular CSS to do what you are describing.

Answer (score 1):

With [CSS modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules#dependencies), you can also compose extending classes from other CSS module by pointing a file:

```
.otherClassName {
    composes: className from "./style.css";
    color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: This repeats the answer by Mikhail from one year prior.

Comment: In my implementation I’m pointing to another file instead of another class in the same file. A helpful detail IMHO

Comment: I don't think that's a particularly critical difference, as the _solution_ being proposed in both answers is still "use CSS Modules' `composes` property", but even so, that difference actually makes this answer _less_ relevant to the question being asked, so I'm not sure you want to rely on that argument in the first place.

Comment: Upvoted because, despite TylerH's opinion, I don't see how this is not a solution to the problem in question. The questioner never specified it must be native CSS and, if they had, then most of the other answers here would also need be downvoted. This is a perfectly valid solution.