# Inherence bootstrap class into my css class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I would like to know if it is possible to create a class that can has all the properties from multiple bootstrap classes.

For example, i have this:

```
<div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-6 col-lg-8 personal-class">...</div>
```

Now think that i am repeating more than 20 times those same 3 col-whatever classes and my "personal-class" all around a project... i was thinking if there could be a way to include the 3 bootstrap classes in this example into my "personal-class".

Like this (Obviusly this is not for real):

```
personal-class{
   col-xs-7;
   col-sm-6;
   col-lg-8;
}
```

Or what would be the most properly approach to this?, i am so lame at CSS, sorry.

Note: I am not asking how to extend bootstrap.

Thank you.

Comment: With regular CSS it's not possible. You might have to use some pre-processor of css like `less` or `scss` or `sass` where you have option for `extend` a style object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extend css class with another style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41635618/how-to-extend-css-class-with-another-style)