# How to conditionally apply a CSS class?

Tags: javascript, css

How is it possible to implement, using CSS only (the worst of cases using some JS) to do the following

global.css (readonly)

```css
.red { 
    color: red;
    /*tens of lines of additionnal css*/ 
}
```

mystyle.css

```css
div[error] {
    background: yellow; 
    apply .red;  //                          << here
}
```

P.S.
The question is **not** about `SASS` or `LESS`.

Comment: Why not use [selector grouping](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#grouping) ?

Comment: it based on what your conditional is that come with the right the solution, can you specific your condition to apply/remove that class

Comment: how are you putting the app into an 'error' state?

Comment: I could find sass's [`@extend`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend) doing what I understand you want to do but I don't think vanilla css can do this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extend css class with another style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41635618/how-to-extend-css-class-with-another-style) this answer say you can't using css only BUT will be able to in css4

Comment: @jonatjano please see my PS

Comment: @Serge I've seen but as I said it does not exists in css3

Comment: @jonatjano yes, but the "duplicate" question accepted the SASS solution, is not my case.

Answer (score 5):

### Plain CSS

If you want **just color value**, you can you can use `:root` variables

```css
/* define color variable */
:root {
  --red-color: red; 
}

/* now you can use it anywhere */
.red {
  color: var(--red-color);
}
```

> Variables in CSS should be declared within a CSS selector that defines its scope. For a global scope you can use either the :root or the body selector.

*This solution might not be supported by old browsers. You can solve this by using some polyfill. Browser support can be seen on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp)*

There is **no way to copy whole class in plain CSS**. Instead of that you can **group your selectors**.

```css
.red, div[error] {
   color:red;
   /* another style attributes */
}
```

---

### In SASS

Or you can use SASS and compile it to CSS. Mentioned on [official site](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend)

> It’s written @extend , and it tells Sass that one selector should inherit the styles of another.

```
.red {
   color: red;
}

div[error] {
   @extend .red;
}
```

---

### In LESS

LESS has a similar sytanx to SASS and has two solutions for this.
You can simply call class.

```
.red {
   color: red;
}

div[error] {
   .red;
}
```

or you can use `:extend` pseudo element which is [described on official site](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature)

```
.red {
   color: red;
}

div[error] {
   &:extend(.red);
}
```

> Extend is a Less pseudo-class which merges the selector it is put on with ones that match what it references.

Comment: Be sure to patch this with https://github.com/jhildenbiddle/css-vars-ponyfill for IE browsers can not handle CSS vars on their own

Comment: I made some edits to my question following your answer... I am aware about SASS and less, also, suppose the .red class is a complex one with tens of lines of code and transformations, animations...

Comment: @Serge So you have to **group** your classes as is written above. There is nothing like a `@extend` in plain css.

Comment: @JaxCze please read attentively the OP, the .red class is readonly, I can't modify it.

Comment: So as I told, there is not way to copy whole class in plain css.

Comment: I use mainly less... frustrated you didn't mention it )

Comment: PS. the CSS variables unfortunately does not work for IE 11

Comment: @Serge It's all written in my answer and Voros mentioned it too.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no conditionals if/then/else in css. Alternatively, you can use javascript/jQuery to apply the CSS dynamically. Something like this.

```
component.classList.add('red');
component.classList.remove('red');
```

Answer (score 0):

Do both in the same rule:

```css
.red, div[error] {
    color: red;
}
```

If it's dynamic, you can't do it with pure CSS - there are a variety of other methods though:

JavaScript:

```
document.querySelectorAll("div[error]").forEach)e => e.classList.add("red"));
```

jQuery:

```
$("div[error]").addClass("red");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generalize them and define them as needed. Even if they're different `.css` file as long as they're not conflicting which each other property they would be applied.

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}

div[error] {
  background-color: yellow;
}

div[error=true] {
  color: red;
}

div[error=false] {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div error>error</div>
<div error="true">true error</div>
<div error="false">fake error</div>
<div class="red">red</div>
```

Comment: if the question would be only about the `color: red`, but imagine the .red class has 10 lines of code...

Answer (score 0):

You can add the selector `div[error]` to the definition of `.red` with the `,` combinator as mentioned in other answers.

But, what wasn't mentioned, it that you can apply more styles to `div[error]`:

```css
/* this will be applied to .red and div[error] */
.red, div[error] {
  color:red;
}

/* this will be applied only to div[error] */
div[error] {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

**Edit:**

If the definition of `.red` class can't be modified, then it's impossible with pure CSS.

Here's a JS solution, that will apply all elements matching the `div[error]`, the class `.red`:

```
function extend(selector, className){
   document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(element=>element.classList.add(className))
}
extend('div[error]','red')
```

Comment: the red class is complex and readonly, can't be modified nor grouped

Comment: @Serge Ok, then it's impossible with pure CSS, but some JavaScript can help

Comment: @Serge I've edited my answer, now it has a JS solution as well.

Comment: yes... the inconvenient of that method is to call this function each time error classes appears in runtime... not so easy...

Comment: @Serge Yes, but there's no other way, as far as I know