# How can use imported CSS classes to style default HTML elements?

Tags: html, css

I have an external stylesheet I'd like to use with a generated HTML page that accepts a custom stylesheet. All the generated HTML uses standard elements, e.g. `<p>` `<h1>`, etc., and a class or id attribute cannot be applied to them.

The imported stylesheet contains classes like `.medium-body-text` and so on.

How can I match up the imported classes with standard html attributes? Basically I want something like this:

```
p {
  [everything from .medium-body-text]
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: not sure to understand your question, but have you tried `p, .medium-body-text { }` ?

Comment: ...well, modify the incoming style to apply generic styles or use Js ie : ` const styles  = getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.medium-body-text')); document.querySelectorAll('p').style.background = styles.background ... ;

Comment: It is not possible with native CSS. You have to use some preprocessor like `SASS` or `LESS`. Does this answer your question? [How to extend css class with another style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41635618/how-to-extend-css-class-with-another-style)

Comment: There is nothing in CSS that will do this for you.