# Combining multiple styling options into one

Tags: css, laravel-9

```
 <div class="flex items-center justify-center " style="width: 100%">
   <button class="mt-2 px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-white transition-colors duration-150
                  bg-purple-600 border border-transparent rounded-lg active:bg-purple-600 hover:bg-purple-700
                  focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-purple" 
                  onclick="window.location.href='{{ route('logboek.show')}}'">
                  logboek
  </button>
</div>
```

I have this button with all of the styling done to it with the class names.

Is there a way to combine all of the styling into one?

like
`.button-style{ mt-2 px-4 etc. }`
so I can use the styling easely with multiple buttons.

I'm using Laravel 9, PHP, Blade, Css, Html ant Vite

I tried picking appart every single one of the individual code sections. And putting them into

button-style{}

Button-style:active{}

and Button-style:focus{}

But that made it not exactly like it was with the normal styling

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extend css class with another style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41635618/how-to-extend-css-class-with-another-style)

Comment: Just... add the styles into one custom class and apply that class?